# My CSV is pulling through correct data, but has html document underneath

Tags: php, html, csv, export-to-csv

Okay so i am creating a CSV from my results. The CSV is correct however has the whole html document of the page underneath.

```
$surveys = $this->apiGet("survey/forProvider",array("serviceID"=>$serviceID,"surveyID"=>$surveyID));
```

This is the data i use in the csv. Now if i print_r() $surveys i get this:

```
Array
(
[surveys] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [EntryID] => 101
                [EntryDate] => 2015-02-10 10:54:54
                [Provider] => Springfield Surgery
                [QuestionID] => 66
                [Question] => What ways are current patients able to access online, physical services at your surgery?
                [Answer] => Patients are able to go online and order prescriptions. Patients can contact reception staff
                [ParentQuestion] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [EntryID] => 101
                [EntryDate] => 2015-02-10 10:54:54
                [Provider] => Springfield Surgery
                [QuestionID] => 67
                [Question] => What are the current average waiting times for appointments at your surgery?
                [Answer] => For a routine appointments\r\n This can be booked 4 weeks in advance. Appointments can be booked up to 10 days in advance or 4 days advance
                [ParentQuestion] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [EntryID] => 101
                [EntryDate] => 2015-02-10 10:54:54
                [Provider] => Springfield Surgery
                [QuestionID] => 68
                [Question] => What options are available to patients for same day/emergency appointments?
                [Answer] => Any patient is able to ring between 8-10.30am each day. Patients are guaranteed of speaking to the GP\r\nA GP will ring back or patients can be referred to the urgent care centre.
                [ParentQuestion] => 
            )
      )
)
```

There is more results but i have shown you a snippet so you get the idea.

Now this is my CSV code:

```
                $dt = date("Ymd");
                $filename = 'survey_export_'.$dt.'.csv';

                header('Content-type: application/csv');
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename;");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");

                $fp = fopen('php://output', 'a');
                $columns = array('Entry Id','Entry Date','Provider','Question Id','Question','Answer','Parent Question');
                fputcsv($fp, $columns);

                foreach($surveys['surveys'] as $survey){
                    fputcsv($fp, $survey);
                }
                fclose($fp);
```

Great, so this shows all the data in the CSV like seen below:

[image]

However if i scroll down the csv i see this:

[image]

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Is this all of the code you have in the PHP file that generates CSV? It looks like you are outputting some code **before** you set HTTP headers (`header()` function). If you have extra whitespace before opening `<?php` tage, try removing it.

Comment: There is on-page HTML being generated by the looks of things.  If the CSV code is the first thing on the page, you could try putting `exit();` after `fclose($fp);` to prevent any more processing, but in my experience you're better off having CSVs generated by a stand-alone page so that you don't get these types of interference.

Comment: Thanks JoeP, this worked if you answer the question i will accept it.